# How to Prove Big-O by Finding Witnesses

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I am having trouble determining a specific and consistent technique for coming up with witnesses $C$ and $k$ when trying to formally prove Big-O.

For example:
Proving that $x^2 + x + 2$ is $O(x^2)$ can be done by making every term in the equation of the highest degree.
Thus, we have:
$x^2 + x^2 + 2x^2 = 4x^2$
Thus when $C = 4$ and $k = 1$ we have proved that the original function is $O(x^2)$

However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to do something like the following:
Prove $x\log(x)$ is $O(x^2)$
If we raise each term to the highest degree, we get:
$x^2 \times x^2 = x^4 $which is NOT $O(x^2)$

I am not sure if this technique is consistent for finding correct witnesses. What, if any, technique should I use that will ALWAYS work?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be to *increase* the order of component functions but do it minimally.

Since $\log x=o(x)$ you can replace $\log x$ with $x$ and have an upper bound on the order, this gives
$$
x \log x<x\times x \Rightarrow x \log x = O(x^2).
$$